# How to mix values of column after ordering by another column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Please, see schema and db-fiddle with query examples:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deals` (
    `id` int(6) unsigned auto_increment NOT NULL,
    `store_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `payment_term` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `initial_cost` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `monthly_cost` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `deals` (`store_id`, `payment_term`, `initial_cost`, `monthly_cost`) VALUES
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('2', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('2', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('2', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('3', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('3', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '3'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('2', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('1', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('4', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('4', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('4', '10', '0', '10'),
  ('4', '10', '0', '10');

  # Just to see dataset
SELECT * FROM deals;

# How it works with simple order by monthly_cost
SELECT * FROM deals ORDER BY monthly_cost LIMIT 0, 10;

# How it should work - mix of store_id values. It's not important to 1,2,3 order. The primary idea is mix, not to see only one store_id during result (if it's possible obviously)
SET @last_store = 0;
SET @last_monthly_cost = 0;
SET @counter = 0;
select d.*
from (
      SELECT *,
             (1 * (SELECT @counter := IF(@last_store <> store_id OR @last_monthly_cost <> monthly_cost, 0, @counter + 1))) as сoef,
             (SELECT @last_store := store_id)                                               as ls,
             (SELECT @last_monthly_cost := monthly_cost)                                    as mc
      FROM deals
      order by monthly_cost
         ) as d
order by monthly_cost, сoef
limit 0, 10
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qXFgAAhn9jCDNvyc4kEzcd/0

See the Query 1 in the fiddle, it shows the current table schema.

I have the next challenge: I have to mix deals that the store_id values are mixed up. E.g. in database stored 20 deals (firstly 15 deals with store_id "1", then 3 deals with store_id "2" and 2 deals with store_id "3"). Limit of query is 10. The result should be the next (the row of store_id values of deals): "1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,1". The next query is good to be with the 10 deals with store_id value "1", because it is the rest of deals.

More problems give me the fact, that in my database stores more then 500 000 deals and the query should be ordered by other columns before it will be ordered by store_id as was described above. And it is paginated (used LIMIT with offset).

See the Query 2, it's a basic query, where 'monthly_cost' can be 'payment_term' or 'initial_cost'. So I need predictable mix of deals by store_id (not random, because every query will give me random deals) after ordering rows by previous rules (monthly_cost, payment_term or initial_cost).

I found the solution. See the Query 3 in the fiddle.
The idea is to calculate coefficient of store_id duplication basing on order. Coef grow until store_id and order column value (monthly_cost in this case) the same. When store_id or monthly_cost are not same as previous - reset coef. Then order by coef in high-order query and deals will be sorted in a good quality. BUT it works too slow, because of I have a lot of rows and SQL must sort out every row without index by reason of coefficient calculation.

It seems like not only database task and maybe I have to do some work on the backend, but didn't find any good solution with good perfomance.

Glad to any help.

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry for the bad prepared question. I hope that made it better

Comment: For the performance issue just use indexes on you filtering fields ...

Comment: @Mohamed23gharbi that's not a solution here, because coefficient calculating in query runtime